# how to flash div after reloading

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to web developement, i have html webpage that retrieves data from postgresql database.
i want to add a class `blink_me` after table reloading using javascript, that div `time` wil blink for 5 minutes if current time is bigger than `row[3]`

```js
    function loadlink(){
        $('#content').load('index.php',function () {
             $(this).unwrap();
        });
    }

    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(function(){
        loadlink(); // this will run after every 5 seconds
        if(document.getElementById("time")){
                var element = document.getElementById('time');
                element.classList.add('blink_me')
       }
    }, 100000);
```

```css
    .blink_me {
      animation: blinker 1s linear infinite; 
    }

    @keyframes blinker {
      50% {
         background-color:#ff0000; 
         color: black;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content'>
  <table>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div id='time' class='blink_me'>$row[3]</div> <!--row[3] contains time hh:mm-->
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For 5 Min use this value and change the last row.

```
   setInterval(function(){
        loadlink(); // this will run after every 5 seconds
        if(document.getElementById("time")){
                var element = document.getElementById('time');
                element.classList.add('blink_me')
       }
    }, 300000);
```

5 Min = 300000 ms

Comment: it's not what i want. loadlink() will refresh table every 'x' sec, and what i want is to hilight div if current time is bigger than div value